# PHP error introduced when upgrading from 5.2.17 to 5.3.27

Tags: php, internal-server-error

Environment:
Windows Server 2012 running Parallel's Plesk v11.5.30 Update #25, last updated at Dec 6, 2013 01:58 AM.

I have a PHP script, which works on PHP version 5.2.17, however I get a 500 server error on one section of code, when I switch to PHP version 5.3.27.

I am using the proper syntax at the top of the header include, first item of script, to display errors but that does not work.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Here is the offending code:

MyScript.php

```
<?php
     // Include PHP scripts.
     include_once( "../Scripts/Header.php" );
     ...
```

Header.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ...
    include_once("myPeople.php");
    include_once("Tools.php");
    ...
```

Tools.php (function fragment)

```
// Create the needed objects.
$oPeople = new myPeople($IdPerson);

// Handle the request.
$oPeople->IsVerified($IdPerson, &$IdVerified);
```

The IsVerified() method trips things. What is weird is that I am only including the file, not executing it. I tried commenting out the function and just having an empty function, but that did not help. The only thing that helps is to comment out the line.

```
function IsVerified($IdPerson, &$IdVerified)
{
}
```

So my questions are:

1. What changed in PHP version 5.3.17 (and later versions, as I tried 5.4.16 and same issue) that causes the script to trip?
2. Why can I no longer see any error message, even though I am enabling error messages?

Comment: check your "error.log" (if you are using apache)  for more details. Here is the _changelog_ http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.17

Comment: According to the manual: *Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed* so it will not always work. You should also set it to `"1"` instead of `"On"` but I don't know if that would make a difference here.

Comment: I am using Plesk on a Windows platform, so no apache, sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are passing by reference at runtime. This generated a waringn in previous versions of PHP and since PHP 5.4 it is a fatal error. Check this example: http://3v4l.org/dQWEt

You need to change this line:

```
$oPeople->IsVerified($IdPerson, &$IdVerified);
```

to:

```
$oPeople->IsVerified($IdPerson, $IdVerified);
```

---

You should fix this of course because it will be a fatal error after next upgrade but however, you are just upgrading to 5.3 and this should therefore not lead to a fatal error. Do you have registered a custom error handler using `set_error_handler()` ? This could be the reason why you aren't see any error messages and the deprecated message leads to HTTP 500 responses.

Comment: Is "Deprecated" an error? It doesn't look like the "Fatal error" didn't start until 5.4

Comment: Depreciated is a warning that future versions may not support the call. But they are never Fatal.

Comment: Oh, I see you just upgraded to 5.3. Have you registered a custom error handler?

Comment: Could the "deprecated" warning have triggered a later 500 error, as it is sent to the browser as text? This is a common problem with the warning triggering the flush of headers and then getting errors because the header() function can no longer be called. I haven't heard of it causing a 500 error, but perhaps there is a way it could. Anyway, fix all such "deprecated" errors and see if it helps with this problem.

Comment: The reference thing is obviously the error now that you pointed it out to me. Thank you, however I am not following. One can no longer use references? What replaces that? How is a class method supposed to return a value / multiple values? Yes, there is the "return ...", but not having references makes things complicated.

Comment: You can still use references, although they are in almost every situation unnecessary from design view of things and can have unexpected side effects. However, passing by reference works by declaring a function parameter as passed by reference in the function definition - and only there. Like: `function f(&$a) {}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That worked and I am updated to 5.4.16.